# Is there a way to use a newer version of MongoDB with Meteor js, as in the one that's shipped with it?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Basically, I've become accustomed to developing with the mongo that's packed with Meteor, not for anything other than development of course.

I'm beginning to run into features of MongoDB in the newer version that isn't available to me with the MongoDB that's shipped with Meteor.

For example, in Mongo, the $sort within a $push no longer requires $slice:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/sort/

Just curious if this is a limitation or if there's a workaround? I can use a remote DB or local one but the quick dev tools are helpful.

Comment: Meteor does not "ship with" any version of MongoDB, it is a requirement that you install your own. The database "files" are only created locally by default. Perhaps part of the confusion here is the difference between operators supported by "minimongo" which is the client side emulation layer and actual MongoDB query operators. As long as your installed server supports them you can use these on the "server" code, but possibly not within the browser code.

Comment: Perhaps my terminology is off but I'm partially confused. I could have sworn that in the past I was able to install meteor and fire up and app without even installing mongodb. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Meteor comes with some pre-builded parts as for Mongo and NodeJS. This should fit optimal under normal circumstances. As I had to run meteor on an ARM architecture, I modified the Dev-Bundler, so that you can use the components installed via operating system. I called it "universal" dev_bundle.

Maybe this is also what you are looking for. Find more at: https://github.com/4commerce-technologies-AG/meteor

Answer (score 0):

Yes!  Just export an environment variable telling Meteor where to look for the Mongo database instance.

```
export MONGO_URL="mongodb://username:password@host:27017"
```

On Windows, add the environment variable to your profile.  Open the System control panel interface (shortcut is Windows Key + Pause), then go to Advanced system Settings on the left, then click Environment Variables.

[image: System Properties]

Under the top section, User variables, click New.  Then enter `MONGO_URL` in the top field, and the mongodb url in the bottom field.

[image: New User Variable]

That should do it!